# MySql Index and constraints

Tags: mysql, t-sql, indexing, constraints, procedures

I need to drop all indexes and constraints and do some processing, after thar I have to apply same indexes and constraints again using MYSql.Please help.

Please suggest if there is some way to store the information/metadata of index created.

Comment: Check the table Information_Schema.Referential_Constraints in mysql

Comment: Why can't you *`disable keys`* and after your other operation re *`enable keys`*?

Answer (score 0):

Start by disabling all constraints:

```
 ALTER TABLE my_tbl NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

Primary keys and unique constraints can't be disabled.

Then reenable them again:

```
 ALTER TABLE my_tbl WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

Comment: By the way, is this question regarding tsql or MySQL..? You have tagged with both, but the solution would be different depending on that.